# Why don't Terrans ever seem to use medics?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-terran

I've been watching a bunch of Starcraft II replays recently, and I just realized that I've never seen a single medic in any of the games. The most recent one I watched had medivacs, which is obviously more useful than medics (since they can lift units too), but most of the games I've seen had a bunch of marines and marauders and no healing units at all.

It confuses me because I used medics all the time in campaign mode, to avoid having to buy more marines all the time. Is there any reason why no one seems to do that in multiplayer?

Comment: I was wondering about the lack of Science Vessels.  ^^

Comment: that would be so OP

Comment: honestly I find it odd that you must build flying stuff to heal your units...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Medics are not usable units in the multiplayer component of Starcraft 2, along with many other units that exist in campaign but not in multiplayer.

Here are the campaign-only units for all races:

- [Terran](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Category:StarCraft_II_Terran_campaign_units)
- [Zerg](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Category:StarCraft_II_Zerg_NPC_units)
- [Protoss](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Category:StarCraft_II_Protoss_NPC_units)

Comment: :D 17 secs, damn my slow internet

Comment: @bronzebeard haha, oh man, mine too. I was just like "HNNNNNGH HURRY UP NEED REPS GOGOGOGOGO". I am a very competitive person it seems.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. I read something about how perdition turrets weren't available in multiplayer a while ago and assumed they only removed tech upgrade units.

Comment: @mana i just want enough rep to change other people's answers >:)

Comment: @Mana The list you posted seems to be incomplete. It lacks Diamondbacks and also the unlockable units like the Science Vessel, Predator or Hercules. This one seems to be better: http://wikicheats.gametrailers.com/StarCraft_II:_Wings_of_Liberty_-_PC/Campaign_Units. Didn't find a page that lists the campaign only structures though (like the fire turret thing).

Comment: @bummzack - They're listed below. It has icons at the top for some of them, but then the lower section has them all.

Comment: Oh yeah. Sorry! I guess I'm an "icon person" :)

Comment: @bronzebeard You have enough rep to change other peoples answers! Your edits require 10k or Moderator approval at the moment, but that's okay, because whenever they get approved, you gain reputation! Go go edit moar!

Comment: i thought it was 2k rep

Comment: 2k rep is the threshold at which your edits no longer need to be reviewed/approved.

Comment: @Sandy I know, I usually leave questions for at least a day so there's a chance for better answers to appear, and a chance for the best answers to get voted up.

Answer (score 20):

medics are not available in the multiplayer version of the game. along with a [bunch](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_StarCraft_II_units#Campaign_Units) of other units

Comment: MOAR MOAR MOAR!!